# How to access arrays inside a structure in pointer format?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have some idea about pointers and arrays.
The array

```
int a[3]={1,2,3};
```

can be accessed in the following way

```
printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
```

or using pointers

```
printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",*(a+0),*(a+1),*(a+2));
```

But how could i access the same array if it is inside a structure ?

```
 struct test{
      int a[3];
  }var={1,2,3};
```

one way is to access using subscript like below.

```
 printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",var.a[0],var.a[1],var.a[2]);
```

but how could i access the same array using base pointer just like a normal array?

```
  printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",var.*a,var.*(a+1),var.*(a+2));
```

the above line gives "error: expected identifier before '*' token" during compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `var.a[0]` is *parsed* as `(var.a)[0]`; think of the leading `var.` as kind of a *path name* for the array object within the struct type<sup>1</sup>.

So, remembering that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, and that in this case `a` is `var.a`, then the pointer equivalent is `*(var.a + i)`.

Hence:

```
printf("array is %d, %d, %d\n", *var.a, *(var.a + 1), *(var.a + 2));
```

Stick with array notation when dealing with arrays; it's easier to deal with, somewhat easier to read, and not necessarily any slower than using a pointer expression.

---

<sup>1.  This is a *horrible* analogy for a number of reasons, but it's the best I can come up with.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @John Bode.I have few more clarification. Which one will have base address here? var? or a?

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",*var.a,*(var.a+1),*(var.a+2));
```

In the case of the structure, var.a is the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Think simply.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int a[3];
} var={{1,2,3}}; /* add {} */

int main(void) {
    printf("array is %d,%d,%d\n",*var.a,*(var.a+1),*(var.a+2));
    return 0;
}
```